# Getting start with ArangoDB and .Net - Exception thrown by AddConnection()

Tags: c#, .net, arangodb

I am hoping that someone who has worked with ArangoDB and .Net and C# can help me out.

When I call `ArangoClient.AddConnection()` an exception gets thrown (of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll). The message is "An item with the same key has already been added."

The call to `ArangoClient` is: `ArangoClient.AddConnection("127.0.0.1", 8529, false, "NancyTest", "NancyTest", "root");`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You most probably already created a connection with specified alias. With a driver version 0.9.0 and higher you can check if the specified alias already exists through `ASettings.HasConnection(string alias)` static method.